# Помогите найти ошибку в регулярном выражении

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pandas, split

Имеется датафрейм "mos1" содержащий столбец "Площадь" где данные записаны в формате 64.1/23/20. (Name: Площадь, Length: 37693, dtype: int64). Необходимо заменить значения в столбце на цифру общей площади из имеющихся данных.
Я пробую вариант:

```
mos1["Площадь"] = mos1["Площадь"](re.split(r"\d*{ ,1}"))
```

Выдает ошибку: split() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'.
Пробую

```
for i in (mos1["Площадь"]):
  sarg= i.split(r"\d*{ ,1}")
   mos1['Площадь'] = round(mos1['Площадь'](i==sarg))
```

Выдает ошибку: 'Series' object is not callable
Помогите разобраться, что я делаю неправильно. Разобраться важнее, чем просто поправить. Задание учебное.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: `Необходимо заменить значения в столбце на цифру общей площади из имеющихся данных` - что есть "цифра общей площади"??

Comment: Кроме того если тип данных столбца `int64`, как указано в вопросе, тогда в данных этого столбца не могут встречаться нецелые значения - такие как `64.1`

Answer (score 2):

В Python синтаксическая конструкция `object(...)` - обозначает вызов функции с наименованием `object`. Об этом вам и сообщает интерпретатор:

> 'Series' object **is not callable**

Т.е. конструкция:

```
mos1["Площадь"](re.split(r"\d*{ ,1}"))
```

будет интерпретирована как вызов функции `mos1["Площадь"]` с параметром `re.split(r"\d*{ ,1}")`. Но `mos1["Площадь"]` - является объектом типа `pandas.Series`, а не функцией.

---

Но главная проблема в том, что вы неправильно используете инструментарий Pandas. В Pandas есть свои векторизированные методы для обработки **строковых объектов** при помощи регулярных выражений.

Т.е. у вас классическая ["Ошибка микроскопа-молотка" или "Ошибка XY"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/) - попробуйте описать вашу задачу более широко и более понятным языком.

**NOTE:** в будущем советую всегда приводить в вопросе воспроизводимый пример входных данных (**в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл**) и **то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе**. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)